# innerHTML returns undefined in react native code for android

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am making a simple android app with react native that get HTML from a site and parse that HTML.
But when I want to use `element.innerHTML`, it returns `undefined`. However, it returns that element correctly.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    fetch('https://www.python.org/').then(res => {
        res.text().then(htmll => {
            parser = new DOMParser.DOMParser();
            try{
                var parsed_html = parser.parseFromString(htmll, 'text/html');
                var elm1 = parsed_html.getElementsByClassName('docs-meta ')[0];
                var elm2 = elm1.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
                alert(elm2.innerHTML);
            }
            catch(err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I am guessing you are using `react-native-html-parser` module. I don't see any `innerHTML` support on its npm page, try `textContent` if you only need to get the node's text.

Comment: textContent worked for me. thank you.